# How do i find the maximum number in an Array using a function

Tags: c++, arrays, function

In my c++ class, i'm supposed to use this " int mymaximum(int a[], int numberOfElements); " function to find the maximum number in an Array. The function should return the largest in this array.

This is the code I have so far without the function I need to use. Thanks in advance and sorry about the messy code, still learning.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
int Array[] = {23,2,90,53,38};
int mymaximum = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    if(Array[i] > mymaximum){
        mymaximum = Array[i];
    }
}
cout << "The Max is: " << mymaximum << "\n";
return 0;
}
```

Comment: what if there are all negative numbers in array better initialize mymaximum as int mymaximum=Array[0]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just wrap around the logic to find maximum in a function. Like this:

```
int mymaximum(int a[], int numberOfElements)
{
    // moved code from main() to here
    int mymaximum = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfElements; i++)
    {
        if(a[i] > mymaximum)
        {
            mymaximum = a[i];
        }
    }
    return mymaximum;
}
```

Aso, in order to support negative numbers, modify your logic like this:

```
int mymaximum(int a[], int numberOfElements)
    {
        // moved code from main() to here
        int mymaximum = a[0];

        for(int i = 1; i < numberOfElements; i++)
        {
            if(a[i] > mymaximum)
            {
                mymaximum = a[i];
            }
        }
        return mymaximum;
    }
```

Note that now I initialize maximum with the first entry in the array!

In `main()` call your method like this:

```
int main() {
    int Array[] = {23,2,90,53,38};
    cout << "The Max is: " << mymaximum(Array, sizeof(Array) / sizeof(Array[0])) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What about negative numbers?

Comment: i know it's trivial.  Every single person that posted an answer made the same mistake.

Comment: In this context, it can't be considered as a mistake! The OP wanted to know how to create and use functions. Whether the implementation was correct or not isn't part of the context.

Answer (score 3):

I'll show the overall structure without solving the homework for you:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int mymaximum(int a[], int numberOfElements) {
    int ret = 0;
    // compute the maximum and store in `ret'
    ...
    return ret;
}

int main() {
    int Array[] = {23,2,90,53,38};
    cout << "The Max is: " << mymaximum(Array, sizeof(Array) / sizeof(Array[0])) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

In case you're wondering, `sizeof(Array) / sizeof(Array[0])` computes the size of the array so that you don't have to hard-code it here.

Comment: As a comment of dubious worth, you don't need parentheses around these `sizeof` operator arguments (they are needed for *type* arguments).

Answer (score 1):

Just move your logic into the desired function as follows:

```
int mymaximum(int Array[], int numberOfElements)
{
    int mymaximum = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfelements; i++){
        if(Array[i] > mymaximum){
            mymaximum = Array[i];
        }
    }
    return mymaximum;
}
```

Put that above `int main()`, then inside `main()` replace the removed code with:

```
    int mymaximum = ::mymaximum(Array, 5);
```

(The `::` wouldn't be needed if either the local variable or the function had different names).

You should then apply the suggestion in sasha's comment to use `[0]` as the initial guess at a maximum.

Comment: Your code doesn't work for an array filled with negative numbers.

Comment: Honestly it doesn't work at all, there's no `return` in that function.

Comment: @TriHard8: I know that - it's been mentioned clearly in the last line of my answer.  The OP doesn't know how to write a function - no reason to assume he can't follow the advice to support negative numbers though....

Comment: @TonyD, okay.  I've been drinking and didn't want to read the entire thing.  Upvoted.

Comment: @TriHard8: sadly, I only feel like I've been drinking... lucky you!  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `for` loop structure with this:

```
int max(0);
max = mymaximum(Array, 5);
```

In the function `mymaximum` use this code:

```
int max(a[0]);
for(auto i(1); i < numberOfElements; ++i)
    if(a[i] > max)
        max = a[i];

return max;
```

Comment: *"replace your `for` loop with ... `mymaximum(Array, 5);`"* isn't quite right... 1) calling the function and not saving the result will leave the local variable unchanged, and 2) their names clash so `mymaximum(Array, 5)` will attempt to do something to the local variable, not use the function.

Comment: @TonyD yep, I was too worried with everyone else not solving for negatives, haha.  I fixed it, thanks.